# Change class in viewport bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to find the best method to change class of my navbar when going into `xs` viewport. currently I am doing this and duplicating content:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-left">
  <div class="sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">

    <!-- Mobile Menu (Turns on @ 760px) -->
    <nav class="navmenu navmenu-default hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" role="navigation">
     <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        @include('layout.navigation.links')
      </ul>  
    </nav>
  </div>

    <!-- Desktop Menu (Turns off @ 760px -->
    <nav class="subnavbar headroom navbar-default subnavbar-fixed-top hidden-xs">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        @include('layout.navigation.links')
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Using `hidden-xs` in desktop view and in mobile using `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` I am able to utilise two separate navs (one for desktop and one for mobile. But Lets say I simply want to change the class when I enter `hidden-xs`? and not have two separate navs. Would I do something like this:

```
$("subnavbar headroom navbar-default subnavbar-fixed-top hidden-xs" ).replaceWith( "navmenu navmenu-default hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" );
```

This above example does not work and my `ul class` needs to change. Is it best practise to simply duplicate the content or should I be changing these classes with jquery?

**Note:** `@include('layout.navigation.links')` Links do not change, just the classes of the `<nav>` and the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chaining of multiple `removeClass()` and `addClass()`:

```
$(".subnavbar.headroom.navbar-default.subnavbar-fixed-top.hidden-xs").removeClass('subnavbar headroom navbar-default subnavbar-fixed-top hidden-xs').addClass( "navmenu navmenu-default hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" );
```

or if you have only mentioned classnames as class attribute.

```
$(".subnavbar.headroom.navbar-default.subnavbar-fixed-top.hidden-xs").attr("class","navmenu navmenu-default hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" );
```

Comment: thanks, I will give this a try and what about the `<ul class="nav nav-pills">` to `<ul class="nav navmenu-nav">`

Comment: that can be achieved using: `$('ul.nav.nav-pills').attr('class','nav navmenu-nav')`

Comment: Getting closer. Your answer has helped but it now replaces `.subnavbar.headroom.navbar-default.subnavbar-fixed-top.hidden-xs` in desktop but show it in mobile. I need to work on my javascript/jquery!

Comment: it doesn't know when we are in desktop and when we are in mobile. the class `hidden-xs` tells it we are in desktop (subject to twitter bootstrap responsive classes) and `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`tell is we are in mobile. Jquery automatically changes the class but it's needs to change when we enter mobile via `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`

see here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: This is class add/remove code and should work in all the cases. try alerting before this piece of code and see if it works in mobile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54450/discussion-between-esotericist-and-milind-anantwar).